# Hazelcast REST API

Tags: java, rest, hazelcast

I don't get to work REST API of  Hazelcast, receiving always :

1. at  client side : `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` via **Browser** or `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server` via a **Java Test Program**.
2. at   hazelcast node:

   ```
   INFO: [myIP]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Established socket connection between /127.0.0.1:5701 and /127.0.0.1:62816
   06-may-2016 13:04:20 com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection
   INFO: [myIP]:5701 [dev] [3.6] Connection [/127.0.0.1:62816] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
   ```

The used code is just hazaelcast [multimap sample:](http://hazelcast.org/)
and the REST API uri http://localhost:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/my-distributed-map/key

Comment: Do you try to access a multimap? Multimaps are not supported, only cluster information, maps and queues.

Comment: Just a map, like the sample program:   ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = h.getMap("my-distributed-map") and also IMap, Multimap ...always the same response

Comment: Is the REST available? By default it should be disabled after `3.6`.

Comment: @Murat, you are OK.  The same sample with 3.5.2 works fine.... I dont know how to enable. I have tried  "hazelcast.mc.rest.enabled", but nothing

Comment: The correct property to enable REST is: -Dhazelcast.rest.enabled=true . This way works after 3.6

Comment: Cheers. `hazelcast.mc.rest.enabled` is for Management Center REST imho.

Answer (score 10):

i think that REST interface was disabled by default until certain version.
add jvm argument for your application.

```
-Dhazelcast.rest.enabled=true
```

Comment: Faced a similar issue after upgrading from hazelcast 3.5 to 3.7.

Answer (score 4):

You can add hazelcast.rest.enabled to your hazelcast.xml config.

```
<hazelcast>
   ...
  <properties>
    ...
    <property name="hazelcast.rest.enabled">true</property>
  </properties> 
</hazelcast>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it programatically, for example using Spring Boot @Configuration Bean, use this method on your returned **com.hazelcast.config.Config** class:

```
.setProperty("hazelcast.rest.enabled", "true")
```

Answer (score 3):

The property `hazelcast.rest.enabled` was removed in Hazelcast 4.

If you wish to do this programatically in Hazelcast 4, you can use the REST endpoint groups

```java
RestApiConfig restApiConfig = new RestApiConfig()
        .setEnabled(true)
        .enableGroups(RestEndpointGroup.DATA);
config.getNetworkConfig().setRestApiConfig(restApiConfig);
```

Or in the declarative configuration

```
<hazelcast>
    ...
    <network>
        <rest-api enabled="true">
            <endpoint-group name="DATA" enabled="true"/>
        </rest-api>
    </network>
</hazelcast>
```